# How do you know the exact address of a variable?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

So I'm looking through my C programming text book and I see this code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int j, k;
int *ptr;

int main(void)
{
    j = 1;
    k = 2;
    ptr = &k;
    printf("\n");
    printf("j has the value %d and is stored at %p\n", j, (void *)&j);
    printf("k has the value %d and is stored at %p\n", k, (void *)&k);
    printf("ptr has the value %p and is stored at %p\n", (void *)ptr, (void *)&ptr);
    printf("The value of the integer pointed to by ptr is %d\n", *ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

I ran it and the output was:

> j has the value 1 and is stored at 0x4030e0
>   k has the value 2 and is stored at 0x403100
>
> ptr has the value 0x403100 and is stored at 0x4030f0
>
> The value of the integer pointed to by ptr is 2

My question is if I had not ran this through a compiler, how would you know the address to those variables by just looking at this code? I'm just not sure how to get the actual address of a variable. Thanks!

Comment: How your variables are layed out in memory, to some extent, is the OS's decision. To contradict that, arrays are sequential. The actual address is never guaranteed, though.

Comment: Also if you execute the same program multiple times, you are almost guaranteed to get different addresses in each execution. It would be an extreme coincidence that you get the same for normal variables.

Answer (score 5):

Here's my understanding of it:

The absolute addresses of things in memory in C is unspecified. It's not standardised into the language. Because of this, you can't know the locations of things in memory by looking at just the code. (However, if you use the same compiler, code, compiler options, runtime and operating system, the addresses may be consistent.)

When you're developing applications, this is not behaviour you should rely on. You may rely on the difference between the locations of two things in some contexts, however. For example, you can determine the difference between the addresses of pointers to two array elements to determine how many elements apart they are.

By the way, if you are considering using the memory locations of variables to solve a particular problem, you may find it helpful to post a separate question asking how to so without relying on this behaviour.

Comment: Adresses are **not implementation-defined**. They are simply **unspecified**. The difference being that the first must be documented, the second need not.

Answer (score 5):

There is no other way to "know the exact address" of a variable in Standard C than to print it with "%p". The actual address is determined by many factors not under control of the programmer writing code. It's a matter of OS, the linker, the compiler, options used and probably others.

That said, in the embedded systems world, there are ways to express **this variable must reside at this address**, for example if registers of external devices are mapped into the *address space* of a running program. This usually happens in what is called a *linker file* or *map file* or by assigning an integral value to a pointer (with a cast). All of these methods are non-standard.

For the purpose of your everyday garden-variety programs though, the point of writing **C** programs is that you **need and should not care** where your variables are stored.

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

Different compilers can put the variables in different places. On some machines the address is not a simple integer anyway.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler only knows things like "the third integer global variable" and "the four bytes allocated 36 bytes down from the stack pointer."   It refers to global vars, pointers to subroutines (functions), subroutine arguments and local vars only in relative terms.  (Never mind the extra stuff for polymorphic objects in C++, yikes!)  These relative references are saved in the object file (.o or .obj) as special codes and offset values.

The Linker can fill in some details. It may modify some of these sketchy location references when joining several object files.  Global variable locations will share a space (the Data Section) when globals from multiple compilation units are merged; the linker decides what order they all go in, but still describing them as relative to the start of the entire set of global vars.  The result is an executable file with the final opcodes, but addresses still being sketchy and based on relative offsets.

It's not until the executable is loaded that the Loader replaces all the relative addresses with actual addresses.  This is possible now, because the loader (or some part of the operating system it depends on) decides where in the whole virtual address space of the process to store the program's opcodes (Text Section), global variables (BSS, Data Sections) and call stack, and other things.  The loader can do the math, and write the actual address into every spot in the executable, typically as part of "load immediate" opcodes and all opcodes involving memory access.

Google "relocation table" for more.  See http://www.iecc.com/linker/linker07.html (somewhat old) for a more detailed explanation for particular platforms.

In real life, it's all complicated by the fact that virtual addresses are mapped to physical addresses by a virtual memory system, using segments or some other mechanism to keep each process in a separate address space.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to further build upon the answers already provided by pointing out that some compilers, such as Visual Studio's, have a feature called Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR), which makes programs begin at a random memory address as an anti-virus feature.  Given the addresses that you have in your output, I'd say that you compiled without it (programs without it start at address 0x400000, I think).  My source for this information is an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13080069/visual-studio-only-breaks-on-second-line-of-assembly).

That said, the compiler is what determines the memory addresses at which local variables will be stored.  The addresses will most likely change from compiler to compiler, and probably also with each version of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Every process has its own logical address space starting from zero. Addressees your program can access are all relative to zero. Absolute address of any memory location is decided only after loading the process in main memory. This is done using dynamic relocation by modern operating systems. Hence every time a process is loaded into memory it may be loaded at different location according to availability of the memory. Hence allowing user processes to know exact address of data stored in memory does not make any sense. What your code is printing, is a logical address and not the exact or physical address.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on the answers described above, please do not forget that processes would run in their own virtual address space (process isolation). This ensures that when your program corrupts some memory, the other running processes are not affected.

Process Isolation:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_isolation

Inter-Process Communication
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication